error in the preamble
I have been working with the same preamble for some time now but this afternoon I get error messages that I don't understand whereas until now it worked perfectly.
I specify that I get error messages even when only putting an empty document as an include file
For example, I have an error "Paragraph ended before @fileswith@options was complete" at the level of the definition of alignedintertext that I copied and pasted from an answer here and which worked very well until recently!
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}  %pour l'option [resume] qui permet de reprendre la numérotation
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs,counter,diagbox,siunitx,varwidth}
\newcommand{\longeq}[1]{\begin{gathered}#1\end{gathered}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{libertine
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{picinpar}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=newline,justification=centering}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{chemgreek}
\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}%le module orbital a été commenté (lignes 3816 à 3824
%+\chemsetup{modules=all}
\DeclareChemTranslation{K-water}{french}{\mathrm{e}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI} %le package physics a egalement une formule \qty
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\alignedintertext}[1]{%
  \noalign{%
    \vskip\belowdisplayshortskip
    \vtop{\hsize=\linewidth#1\par
    \expandafter}%
    \expandafter\prevdepth\the\prevdepth
  }%
}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$x$}}% to be sure the math fonts are computed
\tikzset{baseshift/.style={yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2}}

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\newenvironment{manip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}{\end{itemize}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\usepackage{moresize}

\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}

\usepackage{pgf-spectra}

\def\myentry#1{\tempercolor{#1}%
\tikz{\fill[tempercolor] (0,-.5pt) rectangle (40pt,.5pt)
node[midway,font=\footnotesize,anchor=mid] {\color{black} T=#1\hspace{.1ex}K};}}%

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\LARGE \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*6}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\Large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*5}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\large \bfseries}{\Roman{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\alph{subsubsection}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*5}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\large \bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]{\normalsize \bfseries}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{0pt}{*3}{*0.5}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\newcommand{\expo}{\textrm{e}} %pour écrire e puissance
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}} %dérivée droit
\newcommand{\ddt}[1]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial t}} %dérivée partielle par rapport à t
\newcommand{\ofg}[1]{\og{}#1\fg{}}
\newcommand{\txtmesure}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtpgm}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtprelim}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtmanip}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\txtinterpretation}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\itempgm}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{47}]}
\newcommand{\itempgmbis}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{49}]}
\newcommand{\itemmanip}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{45}]}
\newcommand{\itemcomplement}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{80}]}
\newcommand{\itemcomplementbis}{\begin{itemize}[label=\ding{79}]}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{myframe}{
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=white,
    sharp corners, 
    }

%Oeil pour représentation molécules
\newcommand*\lateraleye{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt, y=0.75pt, yscale=-0.15, xscale=0.15]
    \draw[very thin]  (300,100.33) .. controls (326,122) and (352,135) .. (378,139.33) .. controls (352,143.67) and (326,156.67) .. (300,178.33) ;
    \fill (308.94,116.33) .. controls (313.87,116.33) and (317.86,125.51) .. (317.85,136.83) .. controls (317.84,148.15) and (313.84,157.33) .. (308.91,157.33) .. controls (303.99,157.32) and (300,148.14) .. (300.01,136.82) .. controls (300.02,125.5) and (304.02,116.32) .. (308.94,116.33) -- cycle ;
    \draw[very thin] (314.84,166.6) .. controls (311.87,164.64) and (309.14,162.18) .. (306.76,159.24) .. controls (295.12,144.82) and (296.6,124.33) .. (310.07,113.45) .. controls (311.48,112.32) and (312.96,111.33) .. (314.5,110.49) ; 
    \fill[white] (304.43,124.2) .. controls (306.09,124.25) and (307.32,128.01) .. (307.18,132.6) .. controls (307.05,137.19) and (305.59,140.88) .. (303.93,140.83) .. controls (302.27,140.78) and (301.03,137.02) .. (301.17,132.43) .. controls (301.31,127.83) and (302.76,124.15) .. (304.43,124.2) -- cycle ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\newcommand{\atrf}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Peach,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small ATRF};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\trf}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Aquamarine,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small TRF};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\asi}{ \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(letter.base)]
    \node[
      draw,
      circle,
      inner sep=1pt,
      shade,
      shading=ball,
      circle,
      ball color=black!5!Orchid,
      minimum width=2em,% <--- to get balls of the same width
    ] (letter) {\small ASI};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\RenewChemState\enthalpy{ symbol=H , superscript=0, unit=\kilo\joule\per\mole}
%\newcommand{\argenthalpy}[4]{\ithenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$ }{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$ = \qty{#4}{\joule} }}
%\newcommand{\argenthalpy}[5]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}(#5) $}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}(#5) $ = \qty{#4}{\joule}}}

\newcommand{\enthalpie}[5]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{} \AND \equal{#5}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3} $= \qty{#5}{\joule}}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3} (#4)$}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3} (#4)$= \qty{#5}{\kilo \joule \per \mol}}}}}



%mise en forme des exemples     
\newcommand{\exemple}[1]{\smallskip $\rightarrow$ \underline{Exemple #1 :}}
\newcommand{\exemples}[1]{\smallskip $\rightarrow$ \underline{Exemples #1 :}}


%mise en forme des attention
\newcommand{\attention}[1]{\smallskip \textbf{Attention : }}

%mise en forme des remarque
\newcommand{\remarque}[1]{\smallskip \textbf{Remarque : }}

\def\before@cadre{\par\medskip}
\def\after@cadre{\par\medskip}
        
 % Cadre définition
  \newcommand{\cadredef}[1]{\smallskip
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=lightgray, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=gray, text=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
   #1
            \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Définition};
%\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}\medskip}%
%fin cadre définition

%cadre simple
  \newcommand{\cadremanip}[1]{\before@cadre
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=gray, fill=gray!15, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
%\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=gray!5, text=black]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
   #1
            \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Partie expérimentale};
%\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\after@cadre}%
%fin cadre simple
        

% Cadre formule
  \newcommand{\cadreformule}[1]{\smallskip
\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=black, fill=gray!80, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=10pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[fill=gray, text=white]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
   #1
            \end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, right=10pt] at (box.north west) {Formule à connaître  };
%\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}\medskip}%
%fin cadre formule
                

%Ecrire formules nucléaires
\newcommand{\nuc}[3]{\ensuremath{{}^{#2}_{#3} \textrm{#1}}}
        
    \newcommand{\mathdirectcurrent}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\mathdirectcurrentinner\relax}}
\newcommand{\mathdirectcurrentinner}[2]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1=$}%
  \vbox to .85ex {\offinterlineskip
    \hbox to \dimen0{\hss\leaders\hrule\hskip.85\dimen0\hss}
    \vskip.35ex
    \hbox to \dimen0{\hss
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.17\dimen0
      \hskip.17\dimen0
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.17\dimen0
      \hskip.17\dimen0
      \leaders\hrule\hskip.17\dimen0
    \hss}
    \vfill
  }%
}
\newcommand{\textdirectcurrent}{\mathdirectcurrentinner{\textstyle}{}}

        
        
%Insérer l'équation/figure devant le numéro d'une équation/une figure
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{'équation \ref{eq:#1}}}
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{figure \ref{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} \nameref*{#1}}} % One single link

\setlength{\parskip}{3ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

        \begin{document}
        \frontmatter
        
        \tableofcontents
        
        \mainmatter
        

\include{securite}





\end{document}


The log is quite clear
Runaway argument?
{libertine \usepackage {graphicx} \usepackage {ifthen} \usepackage {x\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@fileswith@ptions was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.53     \vtop{\hsize=\linewidth#1\par

You are missing a closing brace in \usepackage{libertine. TeX is looking for an argument, so it continues scanning until it finds the closing brace. However, on the way is finds the explicit \par, which isn't allowed in a short macro, and throws the error.
Side comment: you should really review that preamble. Multiply loaded packages, wrong loading order, but in general too many packages. I seriously doubt you need all of them in every document.

I second the comment about reviewing your preamble. More does not mean better where packages are concerned.

@karlh https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65812843#65812843
